# Update MySQL column in place

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table as `number` of type varchar(15). This contains phone numbers.
I would like to append a *constant* country code to each of the phone numbers. i.e if the number is 1234567890 I want it to be updated to 911234567890 where '91' is the country code. Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to run a loop through all the rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET number = CONCAT('91', number)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
UPDATE tablename SET number=concat('91',number);
```